# Geometry problem pertaining to right angle

Tags: geometry

So while I was solving this, I marked the correct answer as D, though the correct answer is claimed to be C. What I have read from different books is *do not assume anything from the figures*.  So the solution assumes that the triangle formed would be a right-angled triangle, but it would be wrong to assume that, right?

[image]

Comment: I remember a physics question about a plane in level flight over the earth's surface. The answer depended on whether you could assume it was flying in a straight line, or whether this was an unjustified approximation and you had to assume it was flying approximately in a circle of constant radius (ignoring mountains, prolateness). Being a multiple choice question I couldn't explain the issue, and had to choose. I chose the great circle. A friend chose the straight line. We never knew which was right, but we both understood more than the examiner had allowed. Questions are not always perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, claiming that the solution is C (using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)) would require the triangle to be a right triangle, and **if the actual test you saw this on** specifically instructed you not to assume anything from the figures, then this contradicts their instruction.  But if you only read the advice not to assume anything from the figures someplace else, e.g. in a test-prep book, it's not the fault of the question writers.

Comment: It's a general  gre practice  question.So what will I do for it?